# Apache POIでExcelファイルを読み込むと、Excelファイルが更新されてしまいます。なぜでしょうか？

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

## 環境

- Apache POI 3.17
- JDK 1.8.0_162
- Excel 2016

## やりたいこと

Apache POIで、Excelファイルを読み込む機能があります。
以下のようなコードです。

```
public static void read(File file) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //セルの中身を読み取る処理
    workbook.close();
}
```

今、このメソッドのテストコードを作成したいです。
テストデータ用のExcelファイルも、リポジトリに登録します。

## 問題

上記のメソッドでExcelファイルを読み込むと、Excelファイルが更新され、リポジトリに登録してあるExcelファイルと差分が出てしまいます。

## 詳細事項

### 差分の内容

空のExcelファイル（新規作成時のファイル）を使って、`cmp`コマンドでバイナリ差分を確認しました。

```
$ cmp -b sample-after.xlsx sample4-before.xlsx
sample-after.xlsx sample4-before.xlsx differ: byte 7, line 1 is  12 ^J   6 ^F
```

- sample-before.xlsx : テストコード実行前のExcelファイル
- sample-after.xlsx : テストコード実行後のExcelファイル

### `close`メソッド

`close`メソッドの呼び出さなければ、Excelファイルは更新されませんでした。

## 質問

- 上記のコードで、なぜExcelファイルが更新されるのでしょうか？
- Excelファイルのどういった情報が、更新されているのでしょうか？
- Excelファイルが更新されないように、読み込む方法はありますか？あれば、その方法を教えていただきたいです。（`close`メソッドを呼ばないは除外）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Excelファイルが更新されないように、読み込む方法はありますか？

javaの開発環境が手元にないため、動作確認できていませんが、
WorkbookFactoryの以下の第3引数をtrueにするとリードオンリーで開けるようです。

```
static Workbook create(java.io.File file, java.lang.String password, boolean readOnly)
```

[JavaDoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-java.lang.String-boolean-)には以下と記載されています。

```
@param readOnly If the Workbook should be opened in read-only mode to avoid writing back
      changes when the document is closed.
```

そのため、以下のようにWorkbookを作成すればclose時にファイルが更新されないと思います。

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file, null, true);
```

Comment: 実際に動かして、Excelファイルが更新されないことを確認しました。
`Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file, null, true);`